# How can I use pandas to combine rows in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of dataframes that I combined like this:

```
frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

This gives me an output that looks like this:

```
     name    time    thing   stuff 
 0   a       NaN     X       NaN 
 0   a       10:00   NaN     NaN
 0   a       NaN     NaN     blah
 1   b       11:00   NaN     NaN
 1   b       NaN     Y       NaN
 1   b       NaN     NaN     hi
```

I want to merge the rows so it looks like this:

```
    name   time   thing   stuff
 0   a      10:00  X      blah
 1   b      11:00  Y      hi
```

I've tried groupby but it doesn't seem to work:

```
In:     result = result.groupby('name')
        print result

Out:      result = pd.concat(frames)
        <pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x10cc2bd10>
```

Anyone know how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `groupby` with `first`

```
df.groupby('name',as_index=False).first()
Out[447]: 
  name   time thing stuff
0    a  10:00     X  blah
1    b  11:00     Y    hi
```